# A clarification for a statement in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

The author said: "The remark following Theorem 17.1 shows that every finite dimensional subspace of $H$ is closed "

And this is what is written:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So why by the previous pictures every finite dimensional subspace of $H$ is closed ? could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose an orthonormal basis $\{ e_n \}_{n=1}^{N}$ of an $N$-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, then the map
$$
      x = (x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N)\in \mathbb{C}^{N} \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n e_n
$$
is a Hilbert space isometric isomorphism. So all finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces of dimension $N$ are isometrically isomorphic. In particular, every finite-dimensional subspace of a Hilbert space must be complete. So, if you have a sequence $\{ x_n \}$ in such a subspace that converges to some $y$ in the larger space, then $y$ must lie in the subspace because the subspace is complete, which makes the subspace closed in the Hilbert space. In fact, you can argue that every finite-dimensional subspace of an inner product space is complete and, hence, closed; so the larger space does not need to be a Hilbert space in order to conclude what you want.

Answer (score 0):

They are referring to the remark "The same proof shows that..."

Note the following facts, which you should try to prove if they are not familiar:

1. A subset $E$ of a Hilbert (or Banach) space is closed iff it is complete (i.e. every Cauchy sequence in $E$ converges to a point of $E$).
2. Isometries preserve completeness. (If $T$ is an isometry and $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $T(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence; and if $x_n$ converges to $x$ then $T(x_n)$ converges to $T(x)$.  This is clear because the definitions of "Cauchy" and "converge" are in terms of the distance, which $T$ preserves.)
3. $\mathbb{C}^n$ is complete.

So by the remark, any finite-dimensional subspace $E$ of a Hilbert space is isometric to $\mathbb{C}^n$.  By 2 and 3, $E$ is complete.  By 1, $E$ is closed.